# add calculated row after each row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
Name|Date|Value
"Bob"|2015-07-08|1
"Bob"|2015-08-10|2
"Bob"|2015-09-14|3
"Sam"|2015-10-02|1
"Sam"|2015-11-08|2
```

And I want to compute a row, before each row, which is a simple transformation of the following row (subtract 1 day from "Date" (a datetime object) and reduces "Value" by 1). Like this:

```
Name|Date|Value
"Bob"|2015-07-07|0
"Bob"|2015-07-08|1
"Bob"|2015-08-09|1
"Bob"|2015-08-10|2
"Bob"|2015-09-13|2
"Bob"|2015-09-14|3
"Sam"|2015-10-01|0
"Sam"|2015-10-02|1
"Sam"|2015-11-07|1
"Sam"|2015-11-08|2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply your operations to a copy of the `DataFrame` and stack back together - something like this:

```
In [54]: df2 = df.copy()

In [55]: df2['Date'] = df2['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')
    ...: df['Value'] = df['Value'] - 1
    ...: 

In [60]: pd.concat([df, df2], keys=[0,1]).swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
Out[60]: 
    Name       Date  Value
0 0  Bob 2015-07-08      0
  1  Bob 2015-07-07      1
1 0  Bob 2015-08-10      1
  1  Bob 2015-08-09      2
2 0  Bob 2015-09-14      2
  1  Bob 2015-09-13      3
3 0  Sam 2015-10-02      0
  1  Sam 2015-10-01      1
4 0  Sam 2015-11-08      1
  1  Sam 2015-11-07      2
```

The `keys` and `swaplevel` part aren't strictly necessary, but it prevents having an `Index` with duplicates, which is often easier to work with.

Comment: You could just reset the index as your last step.